# How can I fix my test suites failure to run because of the tcomb-form-native library for React Native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, jestjs, expo, tcomb-form-native

I am trying to perform unit testing and integration testing for a React Native application. When running `yarn test --coverage` several of my test suites fail to run because of the tcomb-form-native library.

I receive this specific error:

`({"Object.<anonymous>":function(module,exports,require,__dirname,__filename,global,jest){import t from "./lib";`

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

  13 | // import { gray } from 'ansi-colors';
  14 |
> 15 | import t from 'tcomb-form-native';
     | ^
  16 |
  17 | const Form = t.form.Form;
  18 |

  at ScriptTransformer._transformAndBuildScript (node_modules/jest-runtime/build/script_transformer.js:403:17)
  at Object.<anonymous> (screens/ReservationScreen.js:15:1)
```

I updated the `package.json` file following the Tests section from the library's GitHub, https://github.com/gcanti/tcomb-form-native, but continue to get the same error.

I'm confused by this line from the tcomb-form-native ReadMe Tests description:

```
  "ios.js"    <<<<<<<<<<<< this needs to be defined!
```

I created the React Native app using Expo so I don't have an ios.js file. The only difference under the `"jest":` from the example code in the GitHub is that I also have `"preset": "jest-expo",` defined.

**What changes do I need to make to my `package.json` file or my test suites in order for my test suites to run?** (They don't have to pass, just simply run.)

---

*Edit:*

I tried adding the following code to `package.json` based on the top answer from https://github.com/gcanti/tcomb-form-native/issues/443:

```
"transformIgnorePatterns": [
  "node_modules/(?!react-native|tcomb-form-native)"
]`
```

I added the code without the original suggested edits from the library's GitHub ReadMe and added it IN ADDITION to the suggested edits. I am still receiving `SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier` when I run tests.

---

*Edit #2:*

I changed changed `import t from 'tcomb-form-native';` to `var t = require('tcomb-form-native');` and I'm still receiving `SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier.`

Comment: var t = require('tcomb-form-native'); <--Change it like this.

Comment: @hongdevelop I changed `import t from 'tcomb-form-native';` to `var t = require('tcomb-form-native');` and I'm still receiving ` SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier.` Do you know if changing the `index.js` file would have an impact?

Comment: I don't recommend it because I don't know the modular architecture that he created.